# Do i really need to hack core to install Amazon S3 Module?

Tags: cdn

I want to run my site through [Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) but to do so i need to configure an S3 bucket and the [Drupal Amazon S3 module](https://www.drupal.org/project/amazons3) requires that i have to hack core. Surely there must be a way around this? Would [Storage API modul](https://www.drupal.org/project/storage_api)e be a way around this?

Comment: +1 from me for avoiding core hacks. Good thinking. And good you asked, it might help others with the same problem but to shy to ask :)

Comment: I think that this was fixed in core, see this patch and entire thread to read more about the issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2305017#comment-9004649 and also the module listed in the answer below is what I have used before for this type of issue and it works pretty good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should give a try to [S3FS module](https://www.drupal.org/project/s3fs)

> S3 File System (s3fs) provides an additional file system to your
>   drupal site, which stores files in Amazon's Simple Storage Service
>   (S3) or any other S3-compatible storage service. You can set your site
>   to use S3 File System as the default, or use it only for individual
>   fields. This functionality is designed for sites which are
>   load-balanced across multiple servers, as the mechanism used by
>   Drupal's default file systems is not viable under such a
>   configuration.